# gpg key, submit to keyserver and find again using webbrowser

Tags: encryption, gnupg, pgp

I am using Kleopatra to create gpg keys (gpg4win).
However, I also want to use openkeychain on android. openkeychain uses pgp.mit.edu as keyserver, Kleopatra uses keys.gnupg.net keyserver.

How can I add mit.edu keyserver to Kleopatra?

I submitted a key to the gnu keyserver. I then used the search box in my webbrowser. But I could not find my key. I found my key using the Kleopatra search function. Why could the key not be found using webbrowser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small hint in advance, because I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly: key servers only exchange *public keys*. If you want to transfer your *private keys*, you will have to do this in another channel, usually by exporting it on your Windows computer, moving a file to your android phone and importing it there.

### Key Servers Synchronize

You don't have to change any settings: (pretty much) all the keyservver synchronize with each other. After some minutes, the keys will be available on all of them.

### `keys.gnupg.net` is not a Single Server

> Why could the key not be found using webbrowser?

`keys.gnupg.net` is a special situation, as it redirects to a whole pool of key servers ([`pool.sks-keyservers.net`](http://www.sks-keyservers.net)). They also have to synchronize among each other before you will reliably find your key on all of them.

---

As your question is already 42 minutes old, the servers should have synchronized quite some time before. Try again, and you will find your key.

Comment: Thanks :)     How about the pgp.mit.edu keyserver? How is this related to the gnu keyservers?

Comment: Have a look at the link I provided in the answer. You will realize the MIT key server is listed in the pool. As `keys.gnupg.net` aliases the pool, you might very well end up on the MIT key server if you have configured `keys.gnupg.net`.